# Fotorama - force resize method

Tags: api, navigation, resize, fotorama

I'm using Fotorama to fill the page with a slide show, and I would like to add a side panel navigation that collapses when it's closed. Fotorama resizes great when the browser window is resized, but it doesn't resize when the containing DIV gets smaller or bigger.
Is there a method in the API that will force it to resize?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the API method for this in the source code
This will force Fotorama to resize and update

```
fotorama.resize();
```